# How to filter intervals (reads or genomic coordinates) that have the exact same 5' or 3' ends?

Tags: bedtools

Say I have reads that overlap some genes that produce small RNAs, but I want only those reads that start at exactly the TSS of the loci. In other words, reads whose 5' end match the 5' end of a genomic feature.

`5'....3'
...+++++++... Gene
...0000000... R1
...00000000.. R2
..000000000.. R3
..00000000... R4`

The output should be R1 and R2.

I believe this is a fairly common bioinformatics operation but somehow it doesn't seem to be an option in the general use tools I looked at (py-bedtools, samtools, bedops).

A solution I thought of would be:

1. reduce the gene coordinates to its 5' end, and
2. using bedtools `bedClosest` to annotate the distance between reads and genes, and finally
3. select reads that overlap (d=0) and write them to a (bam) file.

This involves quite a bit of wrangling data with `pybedtools` or `awk/bash`, and I wonder is there is a more elegant solution to this. Solutions in `R/Bioconductor` are also welcome.

Comment: This method won't work as overlapping segments will also have a distance of 0.  You will have to clip the read coordinates as well as the gene coordinates. 

From the bedtools documentation: 

"-d In addition to the closest feature in B, report its distance to A as an extra column.
 - The reported distance for overlapping features will be 0."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming you have deepTools installed:

```py
#/!usr/bin/env python
from deeptoolsintervals.parse import GTF
import pysam

anno = GTF(["some/gtf/or/bed/file", "or/more/than/one/if you like/"])
bam = pysam.AlignmentFile("something.bam")
for read in bam:
    s = read.reference_start
    if read.is_reverse:
        s = read.reference_end
    e = s + 1
    overlaps = anno.findOverlaps(read.reference_name s, e, matchType=4)
    # For a GTF, parse the results to see if this is the correct type.
    # For a BED3/BED6 file there will be no exons, so anything other than
    # None indicates an appropriate overlap

    do something
```

`deeptoolsintervals` in the GTF/BED parsing and custom interval tree library used by deepTools. `anno` holds the interval tree and the associated information (gene/transcript name or ID, exons, strand, etc.). the `matchType=4` is the pivotal part since that specifies that only overlaps having the exact same start position should be included. Assuming you have a stranded library, you might instead do something like switch between `matchType=4` (the same start position) and `matchType=5` (the same end position) depending on the orientation of the alignment and the the `strand=` of the gene.

Note that you'll need to make a `set()` to hold read names to find the mates (that or jump around the file to get them, which is probably slower).

Comment: Hey @devon-ryan, is this documented somewhere? I searched the DeepTools docs but did not find it. I am looking for other, more tuned, ways to overlap reads with features.

Comment: @fridaymeetssunday This is a semi-separate module, you can find [the documentation for it here](https://github.com/deeptools/deeptools_intervals). It's shipped with deepTools but I never included it as part of the standard API documentation, since I figured it'd be internal use only.

Comment: Perfect. I was looking to see if something like the option `GTF_MATCH_WITHIN` existed (it does :)), though in the meantime I figure that good ol' bedtools intersect will solve my problem for now.

Comment: You can also do that with `findIntersect()` in R, I believe.